# I keep getting a 'property out of scope' error when I run this code

Tags: javascript

> Write a function called "getProperty". Given an object and a key,
> "getProperty" returns the value of the property at the given key.

```
function getProperty(objects, key) {
  if (objects.includes(key) == false) {
    var property;
  } else {
    property = objects.key;
  }
  return property;
}
```

Comment: Are you using some specific lint rules/compiler etc or vanilla JS?

Comment: You need to accept an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could you just add a check if it exists?

```
if(property){
    return property;
}
```

or just declare property outside of the if(), using let.

```
let property = null;
if (objects.includes(key) == false) {
    property;
}
```

*this should work*

Comment: @AnthoniaOlanrewajuFagbeyiro: Please consider accepting this answer. Comments are for improving posts.

Answer (score 1):

Proper indentation makes clear that the block where `property` is defined does not include *any* of the places you are trying to use it.

Answer (score 0):

[.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) is not the function to check this. It is an array function to look for values. You want `hasOwnProperty()`
Also `objects.key` will give `key` property of objects. You should be using [computed property names](https://ui.dev/computed-property-names/).

```js
function getProperty(objects, key) {
                                  
           if (objects.hasOwnProperty(key) == false) 
            { var property; 
            } else { 
                property = objects[key]; 
            }
            return property;
}

console.log(getProperty({ 'a': 2}, 'a' ));
console.log(getProperty({ 'a': 2}, 'b' ));
```

This should be working because `var` are hoisted at top. Even from inside if conditions. You can imagine `property` to have the value `undefined` at the top. Later if first condition is true, nothing happens and `undefined` is returned, else the correct property value of the object is set and returned.